# Run second os in docker

Tags: docker, ubuntu, virtual-machine

Previously, I used Virtual Box to launch a second operating system on a computer. But it was very laggy :( After learning about docker I was interested, can we run other ubuntu on docker on ubuntu? In particular, with graph interface.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is a community for programming-related questions only. Please direct your question to [Super User](https://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker does not has an “OS” in its containers. In simple terms, a docker container image just has a kind of filesystem snapshot of the linux-image the container image is dependent on. All Linux distributions are based on the same kernel, so you could, for example, run a filesystem based on Ubuntu in a container.

A container/image could contain an Ubuntu filesystem snapshot with something like this:

```
FROM ubuntu:21:04
```

However, the container is not in and of itself a virtualized environment in the same way that a Virtual Machine is.